# bad box in align + cases mode

Tags: align, cases, box

Do you have any aesthetically nice suggestion to solve the bad box given by the following formula?

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
text blablabla text blablabla text blablabla text blablabla text blablabla text blablabla text blablabla 
\begin{enumerate}
\item blablabla
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{align*}
\nu : \pi[N] & \rightarrow  N \\
\pi(x) &\mapsto \begin{cases}
          \pi^{-1}(\pi(x))=x & \text{ if } x \in o \\
          \{\nu(\pi(y)): \pi(y) \in \pi(x) \}= \{y : \pi(y) \in   \pi(x)\}=x & \text{ otherwise }
         \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}  
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

One solution can be

```
    \begin{align*}
   \nu : \pi[N] & \rightarrow  N \\
   \pi(x) &\mapsto \begin{cases}
      \pi^{-1}(\pi(x))=x & \text{ if } x \in \on\\
      \{\nu(\pi(y)): \pi(y) \in \pi(x) \}= & \\
      \{y : \pi(y) \in \pi(x)\}=x & \text{ otherwise }
     \end{cases}
 \end{align*}
```

but I do not like the result...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean documentclass and usepackage are needed?

Comment: It is my second time posting here, so I need to practice

Comment: I ve edited the post. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

May this will suit you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   \nu \colon \pi[N] & \longrightarrow N \\
   \pi(x) &\longmapsto \begin{cases*}
          \pi^{-1}(\pi(x))=x & if x $ \in \text{on}$\\[0.3ex]
          \begin{multlined}[b]\{\nu(\pi(y)): \pi(y) \in \pi(x) \}\\[-0.2ex]= \{y : \pi(y) \in \pi(x)\}=x \end{multlined}& otherwise
         \end{cases*}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks very pretty! My following question ist very stupid: how do make appear the image of the code ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm no sure to see what you mean, but there's a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the code window.

Comment: I mean, how did you put the image/picture of your solution on the page?

Comment: In the toolbar of the edit window, the sixth icon (looking like a mountain) is for inserting images.

Comment: @flos: See [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764)